# How to pass variable to pivot table parameter?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to pass a variable into a value filter for a pivot table.

The code gives me errors.

I'm trying to put the x variable into Value1.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
x = "*" + Range("Sheet1!h17").Value + "*"

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivoJtFields("Note").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Note").PivotFilters.Add _
  Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:=x

End Sub
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a typo? (PivoJtFields). And make sure you are on the sheet with the pivot table and the table has the correct Name.

Try

```
x = "*" + Range("Sheet1!h17").Value + "*"

Dim PT As PivotTable
Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2")

Dim PT_PivotFieldNote As PivotField
Set PT_PivotFieldNote = PT.PivotFields("Note")

PT_PivotFieldNote.ClearAllFilters
PT_PivotFieldNote.PivotFilters.Add xlCaptionContains, Value1:=x
```